# ASP.NET MVC 4 jQuery Validation Script Bundle Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I have recentely upgraded a website to use ASP.NET MVC 4 and have the following code to render my jQuery validation bundle.

But I get the following error:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'live'
```

And this error when clicking in a text box:

```
Unhandled exception at line 1234, column 5 in http://localhost:13112/Scripts/jquery.validate.js

0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'call': object is null or undefined
```

My bundle code:

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

My _Layout.cshtml code:

```
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

Here is my rendered HTML:

```
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>

        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js"></script>

        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
```

Can someone point out why this error might be occurring?

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: did your check if bundles/jquery is the first rendered? Make sure that it is loaded before any library

Comment: Added the rendered HTML to the question, can you see anything off in there?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The .live method has been deprecated in jQuery v1.7+ and removed in jQuery v1.9+.

Bugreport: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13213
Explanation:
http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed

> .live() removed
>
> The .live() method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and has been
>   removed in 1.9. We recommend upgrading code to use the .on() method
>   instead. To exactly match $("a.foo").live("click", fn), for example,
>   you can write $(document).on("click", "a.foo", fn). For more
>   information, see the .on() documentation. In the meantime, the jQuery
>   Migrate plugin can be used to restore the .live() functionality.

How to fix:
Download the  [jquery migrate plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) and add it to your bundling:

```
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
              "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
              "~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-{version}.js"));
```

Update: The migrate plugin is now available from Nuget as well:

> PM> Install-Package jQuery.Migrate

Comment: Ah it is adding that, was not aware that it should not be there. However I am getting another error (added to question), can you possibly tell me what is causing it as well?

Comment: O that is not being added manually, that is the result of Scripts.Render()

Comment: Oh, sorry, it was a more delicate reason... see my completely new answer.

Comment: Ah so are we just waiting for Microsoft to update its other scripts to work with the new jQuery?

Comment: You may want to include the jQuery Migrate library which will give you warnings about using depricated or removed items from the api in yoru coddebase. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/

Comment: In lieu of adding jquery.migrate -- I went in jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js and replaced all .live to .on, then the error went away. However, got an error in jquery.validate.js using .call (line 1234).  Back to migrate.

Comment: Good answer, I think it's worth editing and changing to jquery-migrate-{version}.js though as it's already on 1.1.0

Comment: And jquery.unobtrusive and jquery.validate have been updated now so upgrading them should work too. I downloaded the NuGet packages dated 18 Feb 2013, Version 2.0.30116.0 and that worked for me.

Comment: I added jquery-migrate via nuget but still needed to do the bundles.Add fix manually. Works now though.